# Do touch events work with SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, multi-touch

I've been playing around a bit with SVG+ECMAScript, and I find it impressive.

I've recently [found out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events) that (X)HTML5 has a ‘touch events’ specification, so that browsers such as the Android browser, Firefox, and Chrome/Chromium have DOM support for multitouch screens.

Can I access these same events from ECMAScript in a standalone SVG file? (I.e. without any (X)HTML5.) If so, a simple example SVG file would be much appreciated.

Note: By ‘touch events’, I'm referring to standard touch events [as defined by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) and not any proprietary API defined by Apple or others.

Answer (score 1):

There actually was discussion about this and it is possible.

More in this thread -> [Can *you* get SVG on mobile browser accept mouse/touch events? I can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110124/can-you-get-svg-on-mobile-browser-accept-mouse-touch-events-i-cant)